# Unsure why a promise isn't completing

Tags: angularjs, promise

Previously in my angular controller, I had:

```
var getResponse = function () {
    $http.post("api/screen/", { Key: 'banana', value: null })
        .then(onComplete, onError);
    };
var onError = function (reason) {
        $scope.error = "Fail";
    };
var onComplete = function (response) {
        $scope.s = response.data;
    };
getResponse()
```

I was able to see {{ s }} via a data binding on an HTML page.

I then decided to refactor the controller by creating a separate service with:

```
var postScreen = function () {
    return $http.post("api/screen/", { Key: 'banana', value: null });
}
```

And I have this in my controller (with onComplete, onError as the same as previously)

```
var getResponse = function () {
    formulaservice.postScreen(onComplete, onError);
}
```

Now the {{ s }} doesn't display on the data binding for my HTML page.

Comment: You need to call `getResponse()` in your controller code.

Comment: I did that (just didn't include it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In here, you are calling the postScreen function with two arguments, however it does not take any the way you defined it:

```
var getResponse = function () {
    formulaservice.postScreen(onComplete, onError);
}
```

Instead, use `.then` to hook on its completion

```
var getResponse = function () {
    formulaservice.postScreen().then(onComplete, onError);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I realized I forgot to call .then as soon as I posted this. Thanks, and I'll accept this as soon as the timer ends.

Answer (score 0):

Your new postScreen() function is returning an Angular promise object.  You need call .then() on the promise object to do what you want to do.  I would recommend changing your service function to take the callback methods as arguments.

```
var postScreen = function (successCallback, errorCallback) {
  $http.post("api/screen/", { Key: 'banana', value: null })
    .success(function(result) {
      successCallback(result);
    })
    .error(function(error) {
      errorCallback(error);
    });
}
```

Alternatively, you could call .then on the service method as you have it:

```
var getResponse = function () {
  formulaservice.postScreen().then(function() {
    //do something with onComplete, onError
  });
}
```

Comment: -1 this would break chaining and create an overall worse API. See the [then(success,fail) anti pattern](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns#the-thensuccess-fail-anti-pattern).